# Using the One Column with Sidebar and wish to reduce the width of the toolbar

Tags: column

I am currently using the One Column with sidebar Text Layout and the sidebar contains 3 web parts within it and having reduced the width of the web parts, I wish to reduce the width of the sidebar in order for the column to take the main stage. Unfortunately our company does not permit SPD therefore looking to see if there is any code which can added to the page in order to manipulate the width. any help would greatly appreciated.